# How I can set command-delete as a custom keyboard shortuct?

Tags: keyboard, system-settings

I would like to set ⌘+⌫ as the custom keyboard shortcut for an app (Anki). The problem is that I can't enter that key combination in the field next to the Keyboard Shortcut in App Shortcuts in System Preferences. [image]

Does anyone have a solution or a way around this problem?

I would like that particular key combination because Anki has ⌘+⌦ set as delete note, but that is much harder to type because it requires holding the fn key.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. It doesn't appear to be possible to achieve that using System Preferences. I had to use Terminal to directly edit defaults using the following command.

`defaults write <plist name of application> NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict '<name of button in menu bar>' '@'`

For instance, to map ⌘+⌫ to Delete menu item in Anki, I used the following command:

`defaults write net.ankiweb.dtop NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict 'Delete' '@'`

There is an invisible unicode character for backspace behind `@`. To enter it manually, open Emojis & Symbols and type "u+0008".